# Wiring a 7 pin laptop webcam?

Tags: usb, wiring, camera

I'm trying to connect an old laptop webcam I bought for $0.93 on eBay to an Arduino Uno microcontroller.

Since I currently don't know what all the pins on the webcam are used for, I'm trying to connect it to a USB first. I don't have alligator clips, so I'm using jumper wires to connect the webcam and USB cable to a breadboard. I know this question has technically been asked and answered numerous times, however, the particular webcam that I have has 7 pins rather than 4 or 5. I assumed the blue and purple were the data pins because I noticed they were wrapped together before I cut off the connector, but I later realized that the green and yellow were also wrapped together. Then the red and orange, and then the grey was by itself. Whenever I perform a continuity test with my multimeter, it beeps when I touch both the green and yellow (I think that means they are ground).

My questions are:

1. How do I figure out what all the pins are for?
2. How do I connect the webcam if it has more pins than the USB?
3. If the yellow and green are ground do I just twist them together or leave it alone?
4. Does it even make sense to try to connect it to a USB first if I really want to connect it to an Arduino?

WebCam:

[image: Web Cam]

WebCamPins/Wires:

[image: Web Cam Pins]

USB Pins/Wires:

[image: USB Pins/Wires]

Comment: Short answer....NO, you cannot have a functioning a USB Webcam connected to an Arduino UNO. There is insufficient performance or memory to handle video over USB. You could simply buy a TTL serial JPG camera, but even here you will have a slow acquisition frame rate. Perhaps the best place for you to start is with something this: https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/arduino-usage

Comment: `it beeps when I touch both the green and yellow (I think that means they are ground).` ...... no, it does not mean that they are ground, it means that they are connected together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Examine pinout of known chips. There seems to be some memory IC (SOIC-8), where it should be easy to determine which is Vcc, and which is GND. This is the first step, to determine which wire is ground, and which is power. The connector actually says that top (grey) wire is 5V. You should take it as solid hint. Trace it to a ceramic bypass cap; the other end of cap will be ground.
2. If violet-blue form a twisted pair, they could be the data D+ and D-. You should be able to trace them on the PCB. If they are high-speed data, they should stay as parallel traces all the way down to controller chip.
3. Then apply +5V power from USB cable, and watch which data wire pulls up. This will be  D+, the other is D-m, and can be connected to "green" and white wires of USB cable.
4. It is possible that the twisted purple wires are connected to a microphone, so the actual USB data are somewhere else. Then green-yellow might be USB data. Watchig the Pull-up high will tell you which is which.

> Does it even make sense to try to connect it to a USB first

Yes, it makes perfect sense, since it is a USB high-speed webcam. It will work as webcam for PC, and you can make some use of it if it works. However, I am not absolutely sure how do you plan to use a HS USB camera with Arduino, which is a low-end processor and can't have a function of HS USB host.